# RabbitMQ - parellel queue

Tags: rabbitmq

We use RabbitMQ as a queuing system for our client's 3rd party accounts application. There are a few reasons but one is that we can control the speed at which data goes into the application. Sometimes a massive queue will build up and this works really well.

However we want to use RabbitMQ for another application which we'd like to be separate and be more real-time.

- Would a separate exchange/queue work best?
- Do I need a separate console app?

If there are 100,000  messages queued up for the accounts app I'd like other app to process straight way

Answer (score 1):

if you want to handle more applications, one solution is to use the [rabbitmq virtual hosts](https://www.rabbitmq.com/vhosts.html), in this way you have different enviroments and you can also use different users/password to access.

In general the best way to scale is to scale the queues, in case you need to handle an high throughput you can create a cluster and scale the traffic between the nodes.

you should avoid to have one giant queue! .. so more queues more scale!

Comment: Yes the one giant queue is fine for account app, but now an issue when doing different things. VHosts looks a good option. I'll definitely investigate. Cheers.